# date comparison in oracle for the year ends with 00

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

The date stored in my database is `01-01-1900` for field `emp_doj(Data Type DATE)`.

But while retrieving the data, the value is `01-jan-00`, even though formatted with `dd-mm-yyyy`.

I am comparing retrieved date field with some other date in SQL query.

```
select *
form persons
where per_join = to_date(to_char(i.emp_doj,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Here the value of `to_date(to_char(i.emp_doj,'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')` results in `01-01-00`, instead of `01-01-1900`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have got some temporary solutions it currently works for me, I simply changed my select query to

```
select *
form persons
where  to_date(per_join,'DD-MM-YYYY')= to_date(i.emp_doj,'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the question you asked. It is a workaround for the query you used as an example. If both your fields are dates just use: TRUNC(per_join) = TRUNC(emp_doj)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it's your default NLS settings for the IDE you are using that is merely displaying the dates with a two digit year. Oracle does not store dates in any specific format. It stores them in a binary format internally.

Therefore I suggest you check the settings for your IDE and/or database and you will see the NLS date format set to `DD-MM-YY`, alter this and set it to `DD-MM-YYYY` and you will see the dates as you wish to see them.

As for your query, why use `TO_CHAR` and then `TO_DATE`? If `emp_doj` is a date field and `per_join` is also a date then just compare them directly for equality. If you are trying to cut the time portion off your `emp_doj` values then just use `TRUNC()`.

For examples and reference on NLS: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NLS

More here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(emp_doj,'dd-mm-yyyy') from yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks chance, I have tried this but still i am getting the same result as 01-01-00

Comment: You are getting this even when you run the EXACT query @chance has posted?? Copied and pasted?

Comment: @ollie i have tried it before with many failure attempts, But one of senior helped me in this regard. as you mentioned this is not the way i am searching for the solution. but it works for me.